# Stepping through JavaScript code in App Manager?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firefox-os, app-manager

I am using Firefox [App Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Using_the_App_Manager) to upload a [packaged app](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Packaged_apps) to a Firefox OS phone, a [KEON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeeksPhone_Keon).

Now, when I go into the debugger and click on one of the source files, then I see:

> [no source]

*Is it even possible to step though source code using App Manager? If so, how?*

[image: Annotated screen shot]

Comment: what version of Firefox OS are your running?  What version of Firefox are you running?  Also try to download https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App and see if you can step through its code.

Comment: @JasonWeathersby The KEON is running *Boot2Gecko OS 2.0.0.0-prerelease.* Some days ago, I tried out several of the versions [available for download](http://downloads.geeksphone.com/), and that one worked. Other versions that I tried had issues which affected my app. The latest stable version for the KEON I think is 1.1. As for Firefox, it's *29.0.1 on Windows 7 x64.* Following your suggestion, I tried the [boilerplate app](https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App), and there stepping through code works!

Comment: I have seen this happen sometimes when their is an error in loading all the js files.  Can you try to open the app in Firefox (meaning no app manager, just open your index.html) and then launch the tools and check the console.  See if it reports an errors.

Comment: @JasonWeathersby I now found out that if I remove `"type": "privileged"` from `manifest.webapp`, then stepping works. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help by @JasonWeathersby I figured out that the problem is triggered by:

- The app is privileged. Excerpt from `manifest.webapp`:

  ```
  "type": "privileged"
  ```
- The Keon is running Firefox OS [2.0.0.0-prerelease](http://downloads.geeksphone.com/keon/master/nightly-images-keon-master-2014-05-12.Gecko-849b0f7.Gaia-014d16e.zip).

Source code shows up either if I remove `"type": "privileged"`, *or* if I install [1.3](http://downloads.geeksphone.com/keon/v1.3/images-keon-v1.3-2014-05-11.Gecko-c096d5f.Gaia-f71e255.zip) on the Keon.

On Bugzilla@Mozilla, I filed against Firefox App Manager: [Bug 1020948 - No source in App Manager for privileged app on Keon with 2.0.0.0-prerelease](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1020948)